# Splunk: Finding results of a field that have the same peer, but two or more different securityName fields

Tags: splunk

I am trying to search and find results of devices that are presenting two or more SNMP community strings to a trap forwarder.  I am looking for the results to show only when the peer id matches and also doesn't match a regex query and return only those devices that have two or more unique SNMP strings.

As an example, I have a device such as peer="10.10.10.11" and it has two values for securityName.  "trapjunFL" and "trapjunXX".

I then could have another device like peer="10.10.10.12" and it has a securityName of "trapcisCO", but it doesn't have a second securtyName field result.

I would like to find a way that finds the results of when the index has a device("peer") that has two or more securityName values so that I can go and remove the false configuration to lessen the burden on the trap forwarder.  So in the example above when searched, it would only return the result of trapjunFL and show the two securityName strings.

My general search to find valid strings has been something like the following:

index="snmp_index" securityName="trap*"
| regex securityName="(?i)trap...(A[K,L,R,Z]|BH|C[A,H,O,T]|D[C,E]|FL|GA|HI|I[A,D]|I[L,N]|K[S,Y]|LA|M[A,D-E,I,N,O,S-T]|N[C-E,H,J,M,V,Y]|O[H,K,R]|P[A,G]|RI|S[C-D,P]|SP|T[N,X]|UT|V[A,T]|W[A,I,V,Y])"

I was then using '!=' to find the invalid strings and then doing excel formulas to try to make it cleaner to look at, but was hoping there could be a better way through the Splunk search field.

Thank you.

So far none of my queries of joining searches has produced any results.  I am unsure of the approach required to yield favorable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) to do this - there shouldn't be a need to [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex)-out the end (or, at least, not the way you're attacking it so far):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp peer=* securityName=trap*
| stats values(securityName) as securityName by peer
| where mvcount(securityName)>1
```

Comment: Hi Warren, thank you for the response.  I tried your suggestion and wasn't able to get a result from it.  I ran a separate query for a device that I know has dual configuration on a Juniper MX960.
`code`
set snmp trap-group trapjunXX version v2
set snmp trap-group trapjunXX targets 10.0.0.1
set snmp trap-group trapjunNC version v2
set snmp trap-group trapjunNC targets 10.0.0.1

index="snmp_index" peer="10.10.10.21"
| stats count by peer, securityName

peer                securityName count
10.10.10.21 commjunNC 5916
10.10.10.21 commjunXX 5916
`code`

Comment: I'm also using Splunk 8.1.0 if that is needed.

Comment: I removed out the sourcetype and was able to generate a working results and you were totally right on not needing to use the regexp, thank you for your help!

Comment: *generally* it's best to include index and sourcetype when possible @Egotagged :)